# How to make a method get called after a @Transactional rollback

Tags: java, spring-transactions

I have function

```
@Transactional
public class TransactionalService {

    @Transactional
    public void DoSomeThing() {
        //do something
    }

    @Transactional
    public void LogInfo() {
        //do something
    }


}
```

So when DoSomeThing() got an error or a runtime exception, it got rollback. I want whenever the DoSomeThing() got rollback, the transaction will call the LogInfo() method.

I haven't have any idea what to use inside the annotation. Do anyone have idea how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using `@TransacationalEvenListener`-s See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html)

```java
@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_ROLLBACK)
public void logInfo(CustomSpringEvent event) {
    System.out.println("This is called after rollback");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A transaction is rolled back when a runtime error occurs.
Therefore, by getting an error, we can be sure that we have called another method when the transaction is rolled back

```
@Transactional
public class TransactionalService {

    @Transactional
    public void DoSomeThing() {
 try {
    doSomeThing;
 } catch (Exception e) {
    LogInfo();
 }
    }
    @Transactional
    public void LogInfo() {
        //do something
    }
}
```